# Servlet Compiling error

Tags: java, servlets, compilation

I developed simple servlet using Apache Tomcat 6.

Firstly I write simple Hello World print servlet. Then set CLASSPATH for `servlet-api.jar` and compile and copy `webapps/login/WEB-INF/classes/test/HelloServlet.class`. That's working fine.

After I write simple JDBC connection in the servlet. I downloaded MySQL J-Connector and set CLASSPATH like this:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar
```

then try to compile; it then shows the following message:

```
"Unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
```

How should I solve that?

Comment: Btw: the JDBC driver doesn't need to be in the compiletime classpath. You are not importing any line of it in your code, you just have the driver name in a `String`, right? It only needs to be in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your  `Class.forName()`       under try catch block & classpath should ends with (.;) check it once.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception. That means that you are required to deal with it, either by putting the call that may throw this exception inside a `try { ... } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { ... }` block or by adding a `throws` clause to the method declaration of the method in which you make the call to the method that may throw this exception.

Read more about dealing with checked exceptions in [The Catch or Specify Requirement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.